# How do I store each char from a file into an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, readfile

So I want to read a file and then storing the string character by character into a char array.
My input file is just a simple "Hello".
I want to store the characters of this string into a char array so

```
arr[0] = H
arr[1] = e
arr[2] = l
arr[3] = l
arr[4] = o
```

My code is as follow but instead of storing each character, it stores the whole string instead

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("inputfile.c","r");     
    int length = 20;
    char arr[length][50];           
    int i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        char r = (char)fgetc(ifp);
        int k = 0;

        while(r != ',' && !feof(ifp))    
        {             
            arr[i][k++] = r;            
            r = (char)fgetc(ifp);
        }
        arr[i][k] = 0;  

        if(feof(ifp))
        {       
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    int j;

    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", arr[j] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I get here is `arr[0] = "Hello"`
instead of `arr[0] = H`, `arr[1] = e` etc.

Could I get some help as to how I could store character by character from the file and not the whole string?

Comment: `arr` is a 2-dimensional array. `arr[0]` is a string, `arr[0][0]` is a single character.

Comment: The code you've written seems to be for parsing a comma-separated string, it puts each word into a different element of the array.

Comment: How could this not have been intentional, unless you just copied this code without understanding what it's for?

Comment: It's unusual to see the correct use of `feof()`.

Comment: I had some help with this but I did modified it a little so it would read my text file. What I got was that it would read the string in my file and then put it into an array.

Comment: I needed to use arr[length][50] because it's an array of a character array otherwise it won't put the char into my array, this is what I got when I tried looking it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar already pointed out, it's a two-dimensional array. You could probably do

```
for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
    int wordlength = strlen(arr[j]);
    for (int h = 0; h < wordlength; h++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", arr[j][h] );
    }
}
```

Edit: You'd have to include string.h though.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! it made it so now the array is actually of the characters of the first word and not the whole string

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You can mark answers as accepted if you feel like you dont need any other answers, so other people dont waste their time (for lack of a better word) coming up with additional ones.

Answer (score 1):

A string is just an array of chars:

```
char exampleString[6] = "Hello";

printf( "%c\n", exampleString[0]); // Prints 'H'
printf( "%c\n", exampleString[1]); // Prints 'e'
printf( "%c\n", exampleString[2]); // Prints 'l'
printf( "%c\n", exampleString[3]); // Prints 'l'
printf( "%c\n", exampleString[4]); // Prints 'o'
```

Actually `printf( "%c\n", exampleString[5]);` prints... nothing, because (length+1)th character of a string is the null character (0x00); the string terminator.

Since you defined a bidimensional array of chars, each row is a string. Since you store all chars at index 0 (you never increment variable i), `arr[0]` will contain exactly the string "Hello".
In order to access first character of the string you can print `arr[0][0]`, but I suggest to just declare a monodimensional array. Of course make sure that the array is able to fit the maximum file size (dim=maxLen+1), otherwise you will be writing *in the hyperspace*.